# Find patients with multiple gender

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find patients having multiple genders recorded. (I wish I knew how to create a table.)

```
[Hospital Number] [Sex Code]

0000001           M
0000002           F
0000003           M
0000003           F
```

Here we can see patient 1 and 2 are okay, but patient 3 has multiple genders. (There are 4 available genders in the system).

The columns are `[Hospital Number]` and `[Sex Code]` and the table is called `Table1`.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Tip of the day: GROUP BY combined with HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT)!

Comment: MS SQL: *Select hospital_number from Table1 group by hospital_number having count(sex_code) > 1* . You need to translate this query to ms-access syntax.

Comment: Note: your question implies that every hospital can only have two patients: one male and one female.

Comment: @joop, I suppose [Hospital Number] means patient_id.

Comment: Yes, that could be. But it would be a very bad name in that case.

Comment: "I wish I knew how to create a table." -> http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: @joop Yes, Hospital Number is the patient identifier.  The complexities of the patient identifier within the NHS are a bit out of scope for this forum, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Andre451 Thanks for the tip, that little beauty is going stright to bookmark for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution, do a self join:

```
select distinct p1.[hospital number]
FROM patients AS p1
INNER JOIN patients AS p2
  ON  p1.[hospital number] = p2.[hospital number]
  AND p1.[Sex code] <> p2.[Sex code]
```

Return `[hospital number]` if same `[hospital number]` but different `[Sex code]` is found.

Now edited according to HarveyFrench's suggestion!

Comment: @ jarlh 'SELECT DISTINCT [Hospital Number]
FROM Table1 p1
JOIN Table1 p2
  ON  p1.[Hospital Number] = p2.[Hospital Number]
  AND p1.[Sex Code] <> p2.[Sex Code]' gives me Syntax error in FROM clause, but I'm interested in this technique

Comment: It's actually pretty basic. Instead of joining two different tables, you join a table with itself. You need table aliases (e.g. p1 and p2) to make clear which one you're using.

Comment: sorry to hassle you, but I'm still getting syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have never tried MS Access, so I can't help more than this.

Comment: Replace JOIN with INNER JOIN.    add AS after each table name.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a subquery in MS Access.  You can just compare the minimum and maximum values:

```
SELECT [hospital number]
FROM patients
GROUP BY [hospital number]
HAVING MIN([Sex Code]) <> MAX([Sex Code]);
```

This should also have better performance than the count distinct.  It does not return rows where `[Sex Code]` is `NULL` *and* takes on one another value (neither would `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  That is `NULL` is ignored.  That is easy enough to fix, but it is unclear how you want to handle `NULL`.

Comment: luckily for me I cannot have NULL values in this particular db

Comment: Interestingly You're statement gave 3 less results than jarlh and it turns out I do have NULL genders.  Typical.  But it works, so thanks again.

Comment: In that case replace [sex code] with nz([sex code],0) so it can handle nulls.

Answer (score 3):

While in standard SQL you would simply use a GROUP BY query and a COUNT(DISTINCT) like this:

```
SELECT [hospital number]
FROM patients
GROUP BY [hospital number]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Sex Code])>1
```

if you are using Microsoft Access you need to use a different solution, as COUNT DISTINCT is not provided. There are multiple ways to solve your problem, one of those is using a subquery:

```
SELECT [hospital name]
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT [hospital name], [Sex code]
  FROM Patients
) AS s
GROUP BY [hospital name]
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Please note that a subquery with count(*) will include patients that have "null" gender (while a count distinct query will only count non-null values).

You might want to use

```
COUNT(*)>1
```

to return all patients that have multiple genders (and also null and non-null genders). If you just want to ignore nulls you could use:

```
COUNT([hospital number])>1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and comments.  I did try some things but they didn't work so I didn't want to fill the post with unneccessary comments.  Good job fthiella, I'd mark the answer with a plus one if I had enough reputation.

Comment: SQL is generic (Oracle, MS Access etc) I think you mean "In SQL Server ...", which is not really relevant to an MS Access question :)

Comment: @Fionnuala yes, it's not relevant for the question itself, but what I mean is: for MS Access use a subquery (or min/max like Gordon's answer), but if your dbms supports count distinct, better to use count distinct - also it's important to note that a subquery with count(*) will handle NULLs differently from a query with a count distinct

Answer (score 1):

or even simpler.

```
SELECT [hospital number]
  FROM patients
GROUP BY [hospital number]
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: I'm loving the simplicity of this explanatrions, but it has highlighted that the neglected to mention that each record can (and has) multiple entries with the same gender so in the above example there could be multiple entries for patient 1 as M for male

Comment: Is that know as "MultiGender"?  I've not heard of that before.  TransGeneder yes, but what next! ;-)

Comment: Unknown and Indeterminate are geniune options, but we also end up with crap like "4"

Comment: Indeterminate  is concerning, scary in fact.